# Keep lines when remove View from a layout

Tags: android, view

I have this View to draw by following user's finger. I add it on a layout on my Activity with addView when I want him to can draw, and I remove it with removeView when I want him to cannot draw. My problem is that I want the lines he has drawn to appear but they DISAPPEAR! 
Do you have any idea what can I do to change this?

```
public class MyView extends View{
    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;



    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG); 
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    }

    @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        invalidate();

    }


    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know is it true or not but you can do something like this:
1.Take a screenshot of your layout with drawing.
2.Remove drawing view from your layout.
3.Set the background of your layout with the screenshot just taken.

Hope you understand..Hope it works..

Comment: I understand, but I want user can erase these lines if he wants anytime. But that is a good idea if I didn't find something else